# Unable to find method in my Async class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating an Android app that can able to delete data from JSON using HTTP DELETE.But I am facing problem. I have created 2 different files. One of MainActivity and Other one of Async.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    onClickButtonListner();
}

public void onClickButtonListner() {
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
    final String URL = myurl;
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Async asyn = new Async(URL);
                    asyn.execute();
                }
            });
 }
}
```

Async.java

```
public class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {
String murl;
public Async(String url) {
    murl = url;
}

 @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
     HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
     URL url ;
     try {
         final EditText id= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delete_id);
         **showing unable to resolve method findViewById**
         String delete_url = murl + "/" + id.getText().toString();
         url = new URL(delete_url);
         httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
         httpURLConnection.connect();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

So my problem is that my Async class is showing Unable to find findViewById method.

So please help me how to solve this problem
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code as below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
onClickButtonListner();
}

public void onClickButtonListner() {
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
final String URL = myurl;
final EditText id= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delete_id);
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Async asyn = new Async(URL,id.getText().toString());
                asyn.execute();
            }
        });
}
}
```

**Async.java**

```
    public class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {
String murl,id;
public Async(String url,String _id) {
    murl = url;
    id=_id;
}

 @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
     HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
     URL url ;
     try {
         String delete_url = murl + "/" + id;
         url = new URL(delete_url);
         httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
         httpURLConnection.connect();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you @pRaNaY  Now I also want to implement GET, POST, PUT by using single AsyncTask. Currently I have different AsyncTask for each GET, POST, PUT. So tell me how to switch between that. Means when I press Update than update method in async task will run etc

Comment: You can add new parameter at Asynk constructor to implement other method . e.g: `public Async(String url,String _id,String methodType){..}` and use method type in `doInBackground`.